# How is SqlException Number assigned

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqlexception

**SqlException** has the property **Number**.

Then there is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx

and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

And it seems to be one or the other

**QUESTION:**

How is it decided which?

**REASON FOR ASKING:**

I need to catch certain **SqlExceptions** and decide how to deal with them based on the **Number** property but I don't know which list I should look at when it seems like the system is using messages from both, and I don't know what criteria is used for choosing.

**For example:**

- Number 53 - from server error message list (exists on both)
- Number    10054 - from system error message list (exists on both)
- Number -1 -    from server error message list (exists only on server    list)
- Number    121 - from system error message list (exists on both)
  ......

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The theory goes that it's the SQL error number, eg. the server side [`ERROR_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175069.aspx). In other words, the first list.

However there are a number of exceptions reported by SqlClient that occur on the client side, not on the server side. A typical example would be an error like failure to connect to the server, since you did not connect there is no server side error to speak of. For example a bad server name (does not resolve in DNS), in such cases the `InnerException` will point toward a [`Win32Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.aspx) with [`NativeErrorCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.nativeerrorcode.aspx) value of [`ERROR_BAD_NETPATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx). In this case 53, the OS system error code, will be reported as SqlException error number.

Other cases the error reported by the SqlClient is a socket error, like an abrupt disconnect. Again, there is no 'server side' error to speak of, and the SqlException will wrap an InnerException of type [`SocketException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx) (a subclass of Win32Error) with the [`NativeErrorCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.nativeerrorcode.aspx) of one of the well known WSA error numbers, like [`WSAECONNRESET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681391(v=vs.85).aspx). In this case the `SqlException.ErrorNumber` will be 10054, but it's the 10054 from the WSA range, not the 10054 from the SQL Server errors range. I know...

So what are you supposed to do? Make sure you check the `InnerException`, if it's a `Win32Exception` then the `ErrorNumber` is coming from a system error code (OS error). Otherwise it should be a SQL Server error number.

Oh, and then there is `-1`... I *think* that is reported by SqlClient itself (eg. some internal state errors) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Brilliant answer.  It's worth noting that the hex Win32 codes are converted to decimal in the actual exception.  For example we're getting exception number 258 with text *The wait operation timed out.*  258 converted to hex is 0x102, and from the [Win32 codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx) it is clear that error code 0x00000102 matches the error text we're seeing.

Comment: Is there some documentation that guarantees this behavior? The msdn article for SqlException.Number seems to be silent on this.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at the documentation for the [SqlException.Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) property.

This is what it says

> This is a wrapper for the Number property of the first SqlError in the
>   Errors property. For more information on SQL Server engine errors, see
>   SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number.aspx )