# A single method throws same type of exception for different reasons in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I have a method `UpdateSQL()` which may throw exception of same type (SqlException) for two or more different unrelated reasons. Reason 1 = "Invalid connection string" while executing `sqlConn.open()` . Reason 2 = "Some error while executing Stored Procedure" while executing `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. How do I identify the reason for which the SqlException was thrown at the caller method so that I could log a custom reason?

Caller Method

```cs
    try
    {
      UpdateSQL();
    }
    catch(SqlException e)
    {
      // How do i know the reason for which exception was thrown so I could log
      log.LogError(e, "Reason");
    }
```

Update method -

```cs
    UpdateSQL()
    {
      using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("myConnString"))
           {
             sqlConn.Open(); // May throw exception for reason 1
             SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("myStoredProcedure", sqlConn);
             sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        
             // Some random parameter
             SqlParameter myParam = sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", "3/10/2015 2:15:10 AM");
             myParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
          
             sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // May throw exception for reason 2
           }
    }
```

One possible method that I can see is that wrapping the two Sql commands itself in separate try-catch blocks at the Update method. But is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I think it is exactly for this reason that there are often policies to only throw proprietary exception (that is, wrap everything you catch and re-throw it as something of your own). That way you encapsulate vendor dependencies. That said, there is information in each sql exception: a state, a message and a vendor specific error code, which may help you find out what to do. Also, SqlExceptions are (or can be) chained, that is, `geNextException()` may return non-null, potentially pointing to underlying or resulting errors.

Comment: Did you try checking `e.Message`?

Comment: To programmatically check e.Message is usually not a good approach in any circumstance. The ErrorCode seems like a good idea to explore.

Comment: I frankly speaking don't understand what OP want's to log if he already has exceptions with error details and description

Comment: By and large, exceptions aren't something your program resolves by itself so there may only be limited use in inspecting them and programmatically behaving differently. If you're capable of foreseeing a way to programmatically deal with the result of an exception it's often possible to foresee what would cause it to happen  before it does (check that the connection string isn't null before you use it for example). Exceptions are mostly resolved by humans and often developers, sometimes more skilled end users (who can edit a connection string into a config file for example) and to that end..

Comment: ..you're probably better off logging and presenting to a human than trying to get too involved in handling them and repairing in code. All that said, agree with the others in that for SQLExceptions there is a numeric code that comes with each that describes the kind of error and you could do something off of that to guide your user

Comment: This might help. It's IMO way too complicated, but there are numbers and inner exceptions that provide more specific information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894345/how-is-sqlexception-number-assigned

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Let's say I have invalid connection string due to may be incorrect pasword or server details, So i catch SqlException and log with a custom message say ("invalid conn str") but it might so happen that conn string is valid but ExecuteNonQuery() fails and throws SqlException for a different reason for which the SqlException will be logged with the "invalid conn str" msg at caller method which is conceptually wrong. So how do I avoid it?

Comment: The way you tell whether the exception was thrown opening the connection or executing the query is by looking at the stack trace, not writing custom messages in your log describing every operation that could throw so you know how to find the line of code that threw the exception.  This is precisely what the stack trace is there to show you.

Comment: @SwapnilKothriwal (1) You would log not (only) a custom message but the message of the exception (which is hopefully imformative). (2) Yes, of course: As  you suggest yourself, you would try/catch *every single command* that may throw an exception, and handle each one accordingly, for example by logging the user name or the connection method etc. for a connection error, and the failing nonqueary() call with a different custom message logging some application context not present in the actual exception message (which, of course, you log as well).

Comment: Thanks everyone for providing clarity. Seems it is probably better to not log custom message as it would make things unnecessarily complex. I also learnt about error codes which are new to me. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @SwapnilKothriwal Well, I have to scold you (with a wink): This is hopefully the last time you asked here before reading the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to logging especially I would avoid doing any custom logic around `SqlException` and just personally log the Error Message + [Error number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15) for lookup. The reason for not doing this is because logging should be relatively simple and you should not write logic you have to further test.

Typically just log something similar to what the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) share. Here is a more condensed version I typically would use in my logs.

```
Logger.Log(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
   exception.Errors.Select( (error, i) => $"Error [{i}]: {Error.Message} : Error Number {error.Number}" ));
```

---

If you need to perform actual business logic there is not really a great way to handle this other than be pretty explicit and use the error numbers to branch to different logic based on error numbers directly or error number ranges. Something like this should get that job done reasonably well.

```
try
{
   // do Sql stuff here
}
catch(SqlException sqlException) when (e.Errors.Select(e => e.Number).Contains(new []{25})
{
   // Log Something about bad connection string.. 
   // it happens to be 25 from what I've seen 
   // which tbh I cant find the docs for :(
}
catch(SqlException sqlException) when (e.Errors.Select(e => e.Number).Contains(new []{1,2,3})
{
   // Log Some other kind of Error
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible way to go but now I realize that the number of underlying causes that can lead to "Invalid connection string" are too many (for e.g. some numbers are 18456, 11001) which makes this approach a bad choice as you yourself mentioned. Thanks for the tips. Learnt a lot!

Comment: Could you add a note in beginning of the answer stating that avoiding custom message logging in this scenario is suggested as it leads to unnecessary complexity, but for information the below solution can be explored. This would help others reading the answer to know the best approach at the start itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @swapyy28 Thanks for the feedback I made some changes, hopefully this better clarifies the points I was trying to make